# Updating nested v-model with computed propertes instead of watcher in VueJS 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Given the following examplary and simplified component in VueJS:

**MyForm (parent component)**

```html
<template lang="pug">
  user-component(v-model="apiData.user")
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MyForm",
  components: {
    UserComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      apiData: {},
    };
  },
  watch: {
    "apiData.user.stateless": function (value) {
      if (value) {
        this.apiData.user.nationality = null;
      }
    },
  async mounted() {
    const response = await ApiService.getData();
    this.apiData = response.data;   
  },
};
</script>
```

**UserCompoent (child compoent)**

```html
<template lang="pug">
  b-form-group(label="Nationality")
    b-form-input(:value="value.nationality")
  b-form-checkbox(:checked="value.stateless") Stateless
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "UserCompoent",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see, I'm using a watcher for the nested property `apiData.user.stateless` in order to update the `v-model` property `apiData.user.nationality`. Having read the docs, it seems as if I should prefer computed properties over using `watch`.

But how would I use a computed property instead of a watcher in this example? As far as I can tell, computed properties cannot operate on nested values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, watchers should be only used if there is no other solution, as it can cause side-effects and makes debugging a mess. In your case it's probably not necessary.

A computed property is **never** used to update values directly. So it's not an option neither. You should use them where possible, but only for converting values into a different format, as helper values for methods or other computed properties or in the template.

In general you should think about your component architecture. The problematic bit here is that you use an object as v-model value, which can cause side-effects too. Of course you can do it like this, but it more complex to maintain and you have to implement it correctly. Imagine you have multiple components using this object as `v-model` value. In the worst case, the components would override values they should not override. To prevent this you usually use only single, primitive values as `v-model`, instead of objects.

Actually, the way you implemented it works by accident. In Vue 2 `v-model` requires that you emit an `input` event from the child component to the parent component, so the value gets updated in the parent component (check here for more details: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components). In your case it works, because your `v-model` is an object - means the reference to the object is passed to the child component and you are updating a property of this object reference.

So, let's refactor your code a bit (not tested, but the concept should be clear):

**1. Assuming you only have a handful of values to update in the child component**

In your case `v-model` is not an option, because you have 2 model values to update in the same component. Vue 3 would support it (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#multiple-v-model-bindings), but as you use Vue 2 I would suggest to do it by hand:

```html
<template>
  <user-component
    :nationality="apiData.user.nationality"
    :stateless="apiData.user.stateless"
    @update:nationality="onUpdateNationality"
    @update:stateless="onUpdateStateless"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MyForm",
  components: {
    UserComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      apiData: {},
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    const response = await ApiService.getData();
    this.apiData = response.data;   
  },

  methods: {
    onUpdateNationality (value) {
      this.apiData.user.nationality = value
    },

    onUpdateStateless (value) {
      this.apiData.user.stateless = value

      if (value) {
        this.apiData.user.nationality = null // You also could handle it in your child component
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <b-form-group
    label="Nationality"
  >
    <b-form-input
      :value="nationality"
      @input="onUpdateNationality($event.target.value)"
    />
    <b-form-checkbox
      :checked="stateless"
      @click="onClickStateless"
    >
      Stateless
    </b-form-checkbox>
  </b-form-group>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "UserCompoent",
  props: {
    nationality: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },

    stateless: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onClickStateless () {
      this.$emit('update:stateless', !this.stateless)
    },

    onUpdateNationality (nationality) {
      this.$emit('update:nationality', nationality)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**2. Assuming your child component updates many props**

```html
<template>
  <user-component
    :user="apiData.user"
    @update:user="onUpdateUser"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MyForm",
  components: {
    UserComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      apiData: {},
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    const response = await ApiService.getData();
    this.apiData = response.data;   
  },

  methods: {
    onUpdateUser ({ nationality, stateless }) {
      this.apiData.user.nationality = nationality
      this.apiData.user.stateless = stateless

      if (stateless) {
        this.apiData.user.nationality = null // You also could handle it in your child component
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <b-form-group
    label="Nationality"
  >
    <b-form-input
      :value="form.nationality"
      @input="onUpdateNationality($event.target.value)"
    />
    <b-form-checkbox
      :checked="form.stateless"
      @click="onClickStateless"
    >
      Stateless
    </b-form-checkbox>
  </b-form-group>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "UserCompoent",
  props: {
    user: {
      type: Object,
      requird: true
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      form: {
        nationality: this.user.nationality,
        stateless: this.user.stateless
      }
    }
  }

  methods: {
    onClickStateless () {
      this.form.stateless = !this.form.stateless
      this.$emit('update:user', this.form)
    },

    onUpdateNationality (nationality) {
      this.form.nationality = nationality
      this.$emit('update:user', this.form)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I updated the original post with an example of the child component. Maybe that will be helpful. What I'm basically trying to do is: If the user checks the `stateless` checkbox, then the content of the `nationality` input field shall be set to `null`.

Comment: Alright, I've updated my answer according to your description

Comment: Thanks, I get the point you're making here. This sounds reasonable. However there is still one thing I don't quite understand. Let's say the child component does not only have two properties but twenty. Would that mean I need to define 20 single props and pass them from the parent component? Wouldn't that clutter up the code?

Comment: That's correct. I have such components too. Therefore you can use a different approach (I've added it to my answer). Pass down the huge prop, copy the values in the child component and make updates only WITHIN your child component. If anything changes, emit the update up to the parent component, so you can update the original object.

Comment: Great, that's what I have also thought of. This approach seems to work.

Comment: Vue 2 also supports multiple models, through props with the `.sync` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You could let the computed property be about the user-property directly.

Then use get & set:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

---

[edit]

In response to the question by OP in the comments:

Actually - now that you've updated your question with more details, I don't think computed properties are the answer at all.

The accepted answer by @tho-masn is clearly the way to go.

Computed properties with getters and setters are a nice way to create v-model for something, even though that something is computed. I use it in combination with vuex, for instance.

But that's not what you're doing. You want to update property A, when property B changes. That's an event, not a computed property.

I'd delete my answer if you hadn't already asked a question on it.

[/edit]

Comment: Would yo mind elaborating on this, maybe by giving an example?